# How to move video from ionic json request in php to folder

Tags: php, ionic3

I sent a video captured from ionic android  app to request using `headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );`. The video was saved to MySQL but not moved to directory.

My backend looks like this:

```
$postjson = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
//Upload video
if(!empty($postjson['video'])){
$target_dir = "../assets/uploads/";
$video_path = $postjson['video'];
move_uploaded_file($postjson['video'],$target_dir);

}else{
  $video_path = "";   
}
```

Comment: Unless you've actually uploaded the file to your script, you can't use `move_uploaded_file()`. Use `rename()` instead: `rename($postjson['video'],$target_dir);`